# Resizing 'Google maps V2' to take half of the screen instead of whole screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on an Android project right now: what I want to do is having the top half of the screen for the map and the other half for informations that I'd write later on.

My problem is that the map takes the whole screen, I tried different layouts (Relative, Grid) and inflating another layout but the map always takes the whole screen whatever I used.

here's my code:

```
public class Map extends SherlockMapFragment implements IPage, View.OnClickListener {

private GoogleMap    googleMap;
private Marker       marker;
ViewGroup            view;


public Map() {
    super();
}
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_page, null);

    googleMap = getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Event").position(new LatLng(0, 0)));

    final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(48.8146, 2.39525);      

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0f));
    marker.setPosition(latLng);

    return view;
}
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1.0"
   android:orientation="vertical" > 

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1.0"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/infotext">          
   </TextView>

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Once again, the map works without any issue but it takes the whole screen, I really cannot understand why.
Also, I'm using the lib SherlockBar (which cause me some issues to implement the map).

I'd greatly appreciate any kind of help, I'm still kind of new with developing on Java/eclipse so mistakes often happen. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code of the activity in which you call the fragment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have your screen split into two equals parts, you just have to use the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:id="@+id/infotext" />          

</LinearLayout>
```

As you only have two views, you don't have to wrap them into others `LinearLayout`s.

Setting the same weight for the `Fragment` and the `TextView` is the key. It will give half of the screen (in height as the orientation of the `LinearLayout` is *vertical*) for each `View`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I forgot to mention that I already tried using "layout_weight" before and it didn't help T_T
I just modified my xml with what you wrote but the map still takes the whole screen

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind of late, but since I passed by to seek answer for my question, here are my thoughts:

It looks like your linear layout that holds MapFragment is taking up whole screen. Instead of having *match_parent*, change **android:layout_height** to *fill_parent*.

The difference here is that **match_parent** makes the height of the view  to take ALL HEIGHT of the parent. In your case parent is the linear layout that is of the size of the screen.

**fill_parent** actually fills free space of the parent.

For your example the following XML should work:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1.0"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weight="7">

   <TextView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/infotext">          
   </TextView>

     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Having wrap_content with weights allows you to do relative layouting. On my devices, following weights look like that (And you can play with those on your to achieve desired sizes)

```
|----------------|
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|      Map       |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|----------------|
|      Text      |
|----------------|
```

Comment: `match_parent` and `fill_parent` are exactly the same in every way. `fill_parent` was just renamed to `match_parent` to more accurately describe what it does. As you can see here, both are equal to -1 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT (hence the downvote)

Comment: Thanks, my info source was a class in the university I attended to and apparently my professor was wrong. It's good to find something new once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:-

```
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    //import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class Map_Check extends Fragment {

        public Map_Check(){}


        MapView mapView;
        GoogleMap map;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, container, false);

            // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
            mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
            map = mapView.getMap();
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

            // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(48.8146, 2.39525), 10);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            mapView.onResume();
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }

    }
```

And map_view.xml:-

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="150dp">
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
   android:id="@+id/mapview" 
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried this code but still the map takes the whole screen :/

Comment: @LostCid, specify the size of layout_width and layout_height in MapView inside map_view.xml....(If it will not work then specify the size inside LinearLayout). It will sure work, but size should be according to your space...